# Git Checkout shows directory that does not exist locally

Tags: git

Command line with git:

```
Desktop User1234$ git checkout
D   Desktop/repo4321/folder/folder2/folder3/file.txt
Desktop User1234$ rm -r repo4321
rm: repo4321: No such file or directory
```

What is this trickery? I moved the file to the trash and emptied the trash. repo4321 folder does not exist anywhere on my computer, but it still shows on git checkout...

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is,

First, you deleted the folder.
Then you ran `git checkout` command, which shows the previously deleted folder.

It is because, you did not commit to git after deleting the folder.

After deleting the folder, you should commit the change to git using `git commit -a -m "Deleted folder"` and then try `git checkout <branch_name>`

Comment: the folder does not show on the online repo, and it is the master branch, so I would rather not mess around with it..hope this additional info helps

Comment: If the folder is not present in the master branch, then you can simply discard your local changes and pull from the remote master branch. This will delete the folder in your local branch.

Comment: Deletions need to be comited to git as well as file changes. To delete a file use `git rm`

Answer (score 0):

```
Desktop User1234$ git checkout
D   Desktop/repo4321/folder/folder2/folder3/file.txt
```

That means, in your local branch, somewhere you commited this file. And then deleted it.

First do this

```
git checkout Desktop/repo4321/folder/folder2/folder3/file.txt
```

So, the file and the directory are back again.

Now find the commit where you added the file. And remove the directory with file by `edit`ing the commit using `git-rebase -i` (interactive rebasing). Or, if it is a solo commit, just `drop` the commit instead of `edit`ing. Or, if it was added in the latest commit, you can just delete them and do `git commit -a --amend`.

And you won't have any trace of working with that file and directory.